# Designing an InfoPath form for Search

Tags: search, infopath

I am new to InfoPath forms. I have a basic idea that InfoPath forms can be used to capture information related to list columns and the data can then be stored in the list on a SharePoint site. However I want to design an InfoPath form which can be used as a search form for searching values in the list.

E.g I have columns like Name and Department in a list. I want to create a search form where if the user enters only Name, it should search for FieldName contains Name; if the user selects Department, it should search for FieldName equals Department, if the user enters both Name and Department, it should put an and condition for both. THis functionality is not possible OOTB for MOSS 2007. So thought to check if it is possible with InfoPath forms.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your request you want to be able to perform a search from within the InfoPath form.  This can be done by configuring a call to the SharePoint Search Web Service (/vti_bin/search.asmx) within a data connection.

Comment: Do u have a link to any article / blog which would assist?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is an expanded, customized advanced search page. Using Infopath sounds like the wrong way to go.

You can add some options to the advanced search page with the search settings and others by extending the Advanced Search Box control.

Comment: Do you have a reference to any article or blog which can be referred?

Comment: The first thing I'd suggest is just looking at the advanced search page to see if it already meets your needs.

Comment: Yes i checked the advanced search page for my needs and seems it does not have the custom columns I need for my search. Probably just the site columns are shown.

Comment: Which columns are shown is a configuration thing, though. You may not need to develop anything. Also look at custom Search Scopes.